# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions error in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, nopcommerce

I have upgraded my nopcommerce site to 3.70 and i have two websites one is static asp site and other one is nopcommerce site both is on same domain.

I have linked both websites like when customer opens my website on `www.mydomain.com` then displayed my static asp site and when clicks purchase button from static site then it redirects to nopcommerce site and my nopcommerce code is inside nc name folder so url for nopcommerce site is  `www.mydomain.com/nc`

I have setup both website on single domain and its working but after some time or after some hours my nopcommerce site is shows an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have solved this issue via replacing `nop.admin` dll then its working but again after some time its gives same error of Could not load file or assembly `'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions'`.

Please give solution if any one know about that error.

[image]

Comment: have you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694551/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc

Comment: have you removed and re-pulished all dll again? NOP has some task that run periodically, see with one is active and fire this problem.

Comment: !!! If you have two apps and 1 .mdf.... you will get this....!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have the required version of the .NET Framework (4.5.1 or above)